# MVC and JQuery UI Tabs - How do I anchor to tabs from various actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, controller, anchor, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a details view for courses.  On that view, I have a lot of information, so I broke it up into nice JQuery UI Tabs sections and everything is great...except...

Some of the tabs have forms on them.  For instance, upload course materials, add tasks, edit rosters, etc...  after I submit any of the forms, I want to perform the action on my controller and then redirect to the details view again, only this time I want to be anchored to the tab that I was on before I submitted.  According to the Tabs documentation, it's just as simple as adding #tabs-4 or #tabs-n to the end of the URL, but I'm not sure how to tell my controller how to do that...

so if one of my form's controller action is (simplified)

```
public ActionResult CreateTask(Task task)
{
    db.Add(task);
    db.Save();
    //I want to go to /details/id + #tabs-4.  How?
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = task.CourseID });
}
```

and then details is (simplified)

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Course course = db.GetCourse(id);

        // How do I tell the view to open #tabs-4 or 3 or 2??
        return View(course);
    }
```

Additionally, I'd like to have other methods that redirect to the same details view, but instead give it a #tabs-3, #tabs-2, etc, so I assume I have to set that up in the first method, and pass it to the details action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl(new { action = "Details", id = task.CourseID });
return Redirect(url + "#tabs-4");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**UrlHelper.GenerateUr**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703653.aspx)l method, passing your anchor as `fragment`.

I would add an extension method to UrlHelper to wrap a call to `GenerateUrl`, as it takes 10 parameters and you do not need to provide all of them manually in all the cases.